# How to "hide" a dropdown/lookup field in NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, jquery

I'm trying to hide a dropdown field in my SharePoint 2013 NewForm.aspx page.  I figured out how to hide text boxes by adding the following code snippet for a text box called "**Name**".  However, when I try do do the same on a dropdown box that looks up job titles from another list, I can't seem to figure out how to hide that dropdown/lookup.  What am I missing?

`$('input[id*="Name_"]').closest("tr").hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a SharePoint column of the type choice - drop-down the HTML control will be a `select` field instead of `input`.

Simply,

```
$('select[id*="Name_"]').closest("tr").hide();
```